For a scheme $Z$, let $z\in Z, t\in \mathscr O_Z(Z)$, what does $t(z)$ mean?
For a scheme $Z$, let $z\in Z, t\in \mathscr O_Z(Z)$, let $Z_t:=\{z\in Z:t(z)\not= 0\}$. The author claims $Z_t$ is open subset of $Z$. But what does $t(z)$ mean?

The image of $t$ in the residue field of $z$.

So in other words $Z_t = { z \in Z \mid t_z \notin \mathfrak{m}_z }$ where $t_z$ is the germ of $t$ at $z$, and $\mathfrak{m}z$ is the unique maximal ideal of the local ring $\mathscr{O}{Z,z}$.
